# How do I use parse and format value translation props with an ArrayInput

Tags: react-admin

I've tested the same callbacks with a `TextInput` and they work. When I add them to an `ArrayInput` they don't seem to be called (I've tried it on child components too without any luck).

In this code sandbox, edit an item to see a repro. There is no console log or string value being appended: https://codesandbox.io/embed/044vnovwmp

This is the code from the sandbox:

```
class PostEdit extends React.Component {
  dateFormatter = value => {
    console.log("DEBUG :: dateFormatter:", value);
    return value + " FOO!";
  };

  dateParser = value => {
    console.log("DEBUG :: dateParser:", value);
    return value;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Edit {...this.props}>
        <SimpleForm>
          <TextField source="id" />
          <TextField source="title" />

          <ArrayInput
            source="backlinks"
            format={this.dateFormatter}
            parse={this.dateParser}
          >
            <SimpleFormIterator>
              <TextInput source="date" />
              <TextInput source="url" />
            </SimpleFormIterator>
          </ArrayInput>
        </SimpleForm>
      </Edit>
    );
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone googling it:
ArrayInput doesn't support `format` and `parse`.
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3193